# Flash Player Detection Inside an Iframe on Facebook App

Tags: flash, firefox-addon, facebook-apps, swfobject, iframe-app

I'm working on a flash player game which runs on Facebook. I'm trying to detect if the client browser have flash player plugin installed using the swfobject.js (version2.2). I game runs inside an iframe on facebook.
Here's my code snippet :

```
<iframe src='....'>

//content inside the iframe
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var playerVersion = swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion();
if(playerVersion.major >= 14) {
   swfobject.embedSWF(......);   //code for loading swf object
}else{
   document.write("<a href='https://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer' alt='To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 14 is installed. Get Adobe Flash player.' id='installFlashContent'></a>");
}
</script>
.....
</iframe>
```

---

The **swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion()** - this is returning me 0, even if i have flash player plugin installed on my firefox browser.

If the directly open my iframe (Right click > This Frame > Open Frame in New Tab), then the flash player is getting detected correctly as:

```
{ 
  major : 28
  minor : 0
  release : 0
}
```

Digging more into the code, I found that the **navigator.plugins.length**
inside swfobject.js is returning me 0, when i run my code on Facebook.

Any ideas on this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of things, I finally figured out, that the issue is due to firefox browser blocking several websites from loading flash contents inside an iframe(3rd party plugin). We were loading flash contents from *cloudfront.net*, which is listed in the blocked list of firefox.

Here's the complete list of websites which firefox blocks : 
[Firefox plugin blocklist](https://github.com/mozilla-services/shavar-plugin-blocklist/)

More information about this can be found here : [Blocking By Domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Plugins/Blocking_By_Domain)